# Цеплять AR объекты на пальцы :)

Tags: unity3d, vuforia, ar

Вопрос, какими технологиями возможно зацепить за палец объект? Может даже уроки есть?)

Сейчас использую Vuforia + Unity и пока что получилось прикрепить только к нарисованному крестику на бумаге. Но поместить метку на кожу, а тем более на палец не получается :(

Буду рад советам и ссылкам на чтиво. Технология любая и система Android или iOS. Единственное чтобы быстро :)

Заранее благодарен :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не думаю что вуфория на это способна в принципе.

Это слишком специфический функционал который, скорее всего, тебе прийдется реализовывать самому.

Неясно по каким точкам пальцы должны отслеживатся, как должна реагировать система если 3 пальца остаются на месте, а один палец отгибается, неясно по каким контрастным точкам должны позиции пальцев вообще отслеживатся. Нкясно какое поведение должно быть если рука повернута и один из пальцев скрыт.

Это комплексная и сложная задача, которую, даже в контроллере Leap Motion с 2мя камерами реализовать удалось +- на нормальном уровне только лет через 5 разработки (довольно дергано распознавался долгое время). А ты хочешь одной камерой обойтись на софте который заточен под другие задачи.

Но если предположить, что, хотя бы в теории, вуфория это сможет сделать(во что лично мне слабо верится) то даный вопрос следует задавать на форумах по вуфории или же в техподдержку вуфории, а не на SO.